# UItableview inside a popup

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

I am wanting to popup a tableview inside another view controller.
So I have a button inside the mainview controller and inside the action event of the button, I have the following code.

```
SettingsViewController *mySettings = [[SettingsViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
UINavigationController *settingsNavigator = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:mySettings];
settingsPopover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:settingsNavigator];
mySettings.title = @"Custom Settings";

[settingsPopover setDelegate:self];
[settingsPopover setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 400)];
[settingsPopover presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:sender permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

The tableviewcontroller is inside the storyboard with a label in one of the static cells.

Problem: The tableview is popping up. However, the label is invisible. Any ideas?

By the way, I have already removed the default tableview events from the SettingsViewController.

Thanks all for your suggestions.

Cheers,
Prasad.

Answer (score 0):

You can only use static UITableViews with storyboards. If you're not using a storyboard, you can create a storyboard with only 1 view controller in it and have a static UITableView in it. Make sure you assign the view controller's class to your SettingsViewController class. You'll have to specify an identifier for your viewcontroller.

```
UIStoryboard *settingsViewControllerStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"<storyboard filename>" bundle:nil];
SettingsViewcontroller *mySettings = [settingsViewControllerStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"<controller identifier>"];
```

Comment: In my case I am using a storyboard. and the settingviewcontroller is a tableviewcontroller on the storyboard (with a label in one of its cells). So I went ahead and changed the initiating line to: SettingsViewController *mySettings = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"mysomething"]; Still no change. Label is not visible.

Comment: ...something really stupid solved the problem. The problem was this line..[settingsPopover setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 400)]; I was all the while thinking that the CGmake takes the whole view and resizes it to 320, 400. Apparently..it just chooses these dimensions from 0, 0 origin....I placed the label in the top left corner of the cell and it is now visible. really weird. Can you please clarify?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you expected it to do.

Comment: Simon..what I intended was to popover the settingsview (with the tableview in it) near the button that was clicked.